# Which JDBC driver version should I use to access PostgreSQL 9.5?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, cmdb

I installed PostgreSQL on my Ubuntu 16.04 using apt install - it installed PostgreSQL 9.5.12. I want to use cmdbuild 2.5. It gives me 9.4.1204 JDBC driver by default in tar.gz install file.

But I have some wrong with install cmdbuild, so I think that driver version is wrong.

The database driver is here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

But there is no 9.5, it's 42?

Which driver should I download if I want to connect postgresql 9.5.12?

Comment: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/faq.html#versioning

Comment: I do wonder: did you not see the _"It supports PostgreSQL 8.2 or newer and requires Java 6 or newer."_ on the page you link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like the page you link to says:

- If you are using Java 8 or newer, 42.2.2 JDBC 42.
- If you are using Java 7, 42.2.2 JDBC 41.
- If you are using Java 6, 42.2.2 JDBC 4.

As the page says, it supports PostgreSQL 8.2 or newer.